# how to join two table in odata4j

Tags: java, android, odata4j

I want to fetch data from two tables, `Employee` and `Education`, in odata4j. The common column is `EmployeeId`.

How can I join the tables? I use this for fetching data but it takes more time then expected.

```
private void DataListPosition() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                ConnectionOData4j connectionClass = new ConnectionOData4j(context);
                ODataConsumer consumer = connectionClass.getConnection();

                for(OEntity entity : consumer.getEntities("Employee").execute()){

                    final String name=entity.getProperty("Name" , String.class).getValue();

                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                          EmployeeName=name;

                        }
                    });
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                final String strError=e.getMessage();
                ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(context, strError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();


}
private void DataListEducation() {

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                ConnectionOData4j connectionClass = new ConnectionOData4j(context);
                ODataConsumer consumer = connectionClass.getConnection();


                for(OEntity entity : consumer.getEntities("Education").execute()){

                    final String education=entity.getProperty("Education" , String.class).getValue();

                    ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                        EmployeeEducation=education;

                        }
                    });
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {
                final String strError=e.getMessage();
                ((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(context, strError, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }
    }.execute();


}
```

Comment: I have edited your code to add inline code markers (backticks) for inline code, and to _remove_ the inline code markers for your code block. Code blocks on Stack Overflow should not have backticks. Instead, select the block and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K. This will indent the whole block by 4 spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code. I also added the [tag:odata4j] tag for better visibility. Good luck!

Comment: thanks Chris. do you know the solution....

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I'm not an Android developer and I've never used odata4j.